# windows-machine-learning - "No suitable kernel definition found for op Add"

Tags: windows-machine-learning

Running latest [WinMLRunning](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning) but getting error:

> No suitable kernel definition found for op Add (node InceptionV1/InceptionV1/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm)

I converted custom inference frozen Inception model to ONNX using VS or mmdnn. I'm getting similar error when writing new Win32 WinML desktop application from scratch.

> ```
> OS: 17758 insider preview
> SDK : 17754 insider preview
> VS: 15.8.4
>
> WinML Runner
> GPU: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
>
> =================================================================
> Name: tf2onnx
> Author: tf2onnx
> Version: 9223372036854775807
> Domain:
> Description:
> Path: test3.onnx
> Support FP16: false
>
> Input Feature Info:
> Name: input:0
> Feature Kind: Float
>
> Output Feature Info:
> Name: InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Reshape_1:0
> Feature Kind: Float
>
> =================================================================
>
> Loading model...[SUCCESS]
> Creating session [FAILED]
> No suitable kernel definition found for op Add (node InceptionV1/InceptionV1/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm)
>
> =================================================================
> Name: tf2onnx
> Author: tf2onnx
> Version: 9223372036854775807
> Domain:
> Description:
> Path: test3.onnx
> Support FP16: false
>
> Input Feature Info:
> Name: input:0
> Feature Kind: Float
>
> Output Feature Info:
> Name: InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Reshape_1:0
> Feature Kind: Float
>
> =================================================================
>
> Loading model...[SUCCESS]
> Creating session [FAILED]
> No suitable kernel definition found for op Add (node InceptionV1/InceptionV1/Conv2d_1a_7x7/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that your operator set version is up to date. To check the version, open the model with [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron), click the input node and check the Imports field.

We want: **ai.onnx v7** for ONNX Operator Set Version 7 which is the minimum version Windows Machine Learning API supports.

Try using the tf2onnx converter tool to convert from tensorflow. You may also need to update your ONNX python package. We support **ONNX 1.2.2 or higher**: https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx

This issue was resolved here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-Machine-Learning/issues/50